# Mongoose findOne sending null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to edit a discord bot made in python (I stored data initially in python) and transferring it to javascript (node.js) and can't feature out while connecting to my old db why findOne giving me null while providing proper discord id.

*Without anything inside*
Code

```js
anifarm.findOne();
```

Output

```json
{
  _id: 707876147324518400,
  farmed: 17,
  ordered: 5,
  pimage: 'https://media.tenor.com/images/e830217a5d9926788ef25119955edc7f/tenor.gif',
  pstatus: 'I want you to be happy. I want you to laugh a lot. I don’t know what exactly I’ll be able to do for you, but I’ll always be by your side.',
  avg: 184,
  speed: 2,
  badges: [
    'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856137319149207563/856137435696332800/Black-and-Yellow-Gaming-Badge--unscreen.gif',
    'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856137319149207563/862219383866523688/Front-removebg-preview.png',    'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856137319149207563/862240758768599100/download-removebg-preview.png'
  ],
  setBadges: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856137319149207563/862240758768599100/download-removebg-preview.png'
}
```

*With id inside*
Code

```js
anifarm.findOne({
    _id: 707876147324518400
});
```

Output

```json
null
```

anifarm in the schema.
Decleared Schema

```js
module.exports = mongoose.model('anifarm', new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: Number,
        farmed: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        ordered: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        pimage: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        },
        pstatus: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        },
        avg: {
            type: Number,
            default: 200
        },
        speed: {
            type: Number,
            default: 2
        },
        badges: {
            type: Array,
            default: []
        },
        setBadges: {
            type: String,
            default: ""
        }

    },
    {
        collection: 'anifarm',
        versionKey: false
    })
);
```

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. This problem also happens with .find()
Nothing inside find fetches everything by if I provide id it sends a empty array.
A Little help would be appreciated

Comment: maybe the _id is not a number, but a BSON object? mongoose can convert string to BSON, try it with _id: "707876147324518400"

Comment: I tried the possibility before posting the question. And sadly same result `null`.

Comment: Maybe remove _id from Schema? It will automatically add that to the schema

Comment: Removing _id is now giving me this error
`Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "707876147324518400" (type number) at path "_id" for model "anifarm"`

Comment: you cant't pass an id as a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you problem use `mongoose-long` that should fix your problem.

This library will handle all long type data for mongoose since mongoose cannot handle long type data

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass an id as a number, you will have to use `ObjectId` to convert the `id` to an `instanceof` `ObjectId`

Change your code like this

```
anifarm.findOne({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(707876147324518400);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Your solution is giving me the following error `RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= 0 and <= 4294967295. Received 707_876_147_324_518_40`   

I previously used python to create and store data. At that time I had send `int` in _id and after checking mongodb.com it has stored the _id in BigInt format. But mongoose dosen't have BigInt, It only supports Number

Comment: please mention that you have used python for storing data in DB intially

Comment: try this `_id:BigInt(value)`

Comment: Yes I have already tried it previously and since mongoose only supports Number its showing me `CastError`

Comment: can you post an entry of how your values are stored in DB?

Comment: Yes I have tried saving and it works like normal. considering _id as int (or discord user id)

Comment: No, saving any data works. Fetching any default data (Like every data for .find() or the 1st record for .findOne() ) works. But finding any specific data sends `null` or a empty array (for .find())

Comment: can check the `typeof` value of the `_id` returned in any query?

Comment: if the `typeof` value of the id is `ObjectID` then do this `let newId = new ObjectId(BigInt(value).toString(16));` and `_id:newId`

Comment: `typeof` of `_id` has returned number

Answer (score 0):

If you're querying by _id, use `findById()` instead.

```
anifarm.findById("707876147324518400")
```

Official docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Comment: Yes I tried it already. It is also sending null

Comment: @bartickmaiti have you tried with ""? `anifarm.findById("707876147324518400");`

Comment: Yes I have tried still the output was nuill

Comment: @bartickmaiti I tried your code and it worked, I can't think what could be wrong.